# What causes `Prelude.chr: bad argument`?

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, command-line-arguments, caesar-cipher, haskell-prelude

I have the following Haskell program I wrote, the purpose of which is to function like a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

```hs
  1 import System.IO
  2 import System.Environment
  3 import System.Exit
  4 import Data.Char
  5 
  6 shiftRight :: Int -> Char -> Char
  7 shiftRight shift char = do
  8   if isAsciiLower char
  9   then if (toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char) > 'z'
 10     then shiftRight (shift - 26) char
 11     else toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char
 12   else if isAsciiUpper char
 13     then if (toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char) > 'Z'
 14       then shiftRight (shift - 26) char
 15       else toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char
 16     else char
 17     
 18 shiftLeft :: Int -> Char -> Char
 19 shiftLeft shift char = do
 20   if isAsciiLower char  
 21   then if (toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char) < 'a'
 22     then shiftLeft (shift + 26) char
 23     else toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char
 24   else if isAsciiUpper char
 25     then if (toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char) < 'A'
 26       then shiftLeft (shift + 26) char
 27       else toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char
 28     else char
 29 
 30 main = do 
 31   args <- getArgs
 32   message <- getLine
 33   case args of
 34     [aString, aInt] -> 
 35       if aString == "-encode"
 36       -- `read` converts aInt from string to int
 37       -- `map` is used to apply `shiftRight` to each char in the string `message`
 38       then putStrLn $ show $ map (shiftRight $ read $ aInt) message
 39       else 
 40         if aString == "-decode"
 41         then putStrLn $ show $ map (shiftLeft $ read $ aInt) message
 42         else do
 43           putStrLn ("Second argument should be either '-decode' or '-encode'!")
 44           exitFailure
 45     _ -> do 
 46       progName <- getProgName
 47       putStrLn ("Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [-encode|-decode] [0-9]")
 48       exitFailure
```

My `ghc` version is as follows:

```sh
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
```

I compile the Haskell on macos (Catalina):

```sh
$ ghc Prog1d.hs -o Prog1d
Loaded package environment from $HOME/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.6.5/environments/default
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Prog1d.hs, Prog1d.o )
Linking Prog1d ...
```

Then I run my code:

```sh
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 1
"BCDYZAbcdyza"
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 2
"CDEZABcdezab"
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 4
"EFGBCDefgbcd"
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 100
"WXYTUVwxytuv"
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 1
Prog1d: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-14)
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 2
Prog1d: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-15)
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 4
Prog1d: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-17)
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 100
Prog1d: Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-35)
```

Why do I get `Prelude.chr: bad argument`? What causes this, and what can I do to fix the problem?

I have read about others who have had this error, but in their case, deleting the `*.hi` files solved the problem. I have deleted `Prog1d.hi` (as well as `Prog1d.o` and `Prog1d`), but to no effect. I feel this may be caused by something in my code, maybe with line 41:

```hs
then putStrLn $ show $ map (shiftLeft $ read $ aInt) message
```

But this line is just like line 38, which works just fine for the `-encode` use-case. I must be missing something obvious.

I am new to Haskell, so please help me along.
I am mostly used to writing code in imperative languages like C++, python, Java, etc. and I am not yet familiar with the ideas and syntax of Haskell and other functional languages.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: I have a theory: my `shiftLeft` function is not working as I expect, and the problem is the output of that function - which causes a problem upon trying to be output to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In my code, I convert a character into its corresponding ASCII code.

For example, `fromEnum 'A'` will give you `65`. The problem is that, if you shift the value off the table of ASCII values, e.g. `-1`, you cause a bad argument error for the `toEnum` I use to compare for checking if the shift went too far.

For example:

```sh
echo "A" | ./Prog1d -decode 66
```

This will take me to line 25 in my program:

```hs
25     then if (toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char) < 'A'
```

`fromEnum char` will be `fromEnum 'A'` which will give me `65`.

Then I subtract from `65` the `shift` value: `66`. So, `65 - 66 = -1`.

Then `toEnum -1` causes `Prelude.chr: bad argument: (-1)`.

That's because there is no ASCII character for `-1` and that value is out of bounds.

This means I simply have to compare int values instead of chars to check whether my shift is out of bounds or not.

Here is the corrected code:

```hs
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import Data.Char
 
shiftRight :: Int -> Char -> Char
shiftRight shift char = do
  if isAsciiLower char 
  then if (fromEnum char + shift) > 122 -- 122 is 'z' in ASCII
    then shiftRight (shift - 26) char
    else toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char
  else if isAsciiUpper char
    then if (fromEnum char + shift) > 90 -- 90 is `Z` in ASCII
      then shiftRight (shift - 26) char
      else toEnum (fromEnum char + shift) :: Char
    else char
 
shiftLeft :: Int -> Char -> Char
shiftLeft shift char = do
  if isAsciiLower char 
  then if (fromEnum char - shift) < 97 -- 97 is 'a' in ASCII
    then shiftLeft (shift - 26) char
    else toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char
  else if isAsciiUpper char
    then if (fromEnum char - shift) < 65 -- 65 is 'A' in ASCII
      then shiftLeft (shift - 26) char
      else toEnum (fromEnum char - shift) :: Char
    else char
 
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  message <- getLine
  case args of
    [aString, aInt] -> 
      if aString == "-encode"
      -- `read` converts aInt from string to int
      -- `map` is used to apply `shiftRight` to each char in the string `message`
      then putStrLn $ map (shiftRight $ read $ aInt) message
      else 
        if aString == "-decode"
        then putStrLn $ map (shiftLeft $ read $ aInt) message
        else do
          putStrLn ("Second argument should be either '-decode' or '-encode'!")
          exitFailure
    _ -> do 
      progName <- getProgName
      putStrLn ("Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [-encode|-decode] [0-9]")
      exitFailure
```

And here is the proper, desired output:

```sh
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 1
BCDYZAbcdyza
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 2
CDEZABcdezab
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 4
EFGBCDefgbcd
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -encode 100
WXYTUVwxytuv
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 1
ZABWXYzabwxy
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 2
YZAVWXyzavwx
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 4
WXYTUVwxytuv
$ echo "ABCXYZabcxyz" | ./Prog1d -decode 100
EFGBCDefgbcd
```

EDIT (2020-09-01): John Purdy gave me some feedback, which prompted me to radically refactor my code. Here is the improved version:

```hs
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import Data.Char

shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift amount char
  -- `ord` is `fromEnum` but only for `Char` types; converts a Char to an Int, 
  -- which gives us the ASCII number for that character
  -- see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord
  | isAsciiLower char && (shifted < ord 'a' || shifted > ord 'z') = shift cycled char
  -- `chr` is `toEnum` but only for `Char` types; it converts from an Int to Char
  -- see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:chr
  | isAsciiLower char = chr shifted
  | isAsciiUpper char && (shifted < ord 'A' || shifted > ord 'Z') = shift cycled char
  | isAsciiUpper char = chr shifted 
  | otherwise = char
  where shifted = ord char + amount -- e.g. 'A' (ASCII: 66) shifted 1 = 'B' (ASCII: 67), so shifted would be 67. 
        -- cycled: the shift amount, but cycled by 26 to start over the alphabet, 
        -- e.g. 'Z' (by ASCII: 90) shifted 1 is 91, so -26 to get 65, which is 'A'
        -- the amount `div` amount makes sure we add or subtract 26 as needed to cycle 
        -- e.g. 'A' (65) shifted -1 is 64, but if we subtracted 26 from 64, it wouldn't cycle us to Z, 
        -- it is in the wrong direction
        -- so instead we multiply by the sign of the amount: -1 - (26 * (-1 / |-1|) to get +25, 
        -- so 65 ('A') + 25 = 90 ('Z')
        cycled = amount - ((amount `div` abs (amount)) * 26) 

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  message <- getLine
  case args of
      -- `read` converts aInt from string to int
      -- `map` is used to apply `shiftRight` to each char in the string `message`
    ["-encode", aInt] -> putStrLn $ map (shift $ read $ aInt) message
    ["-decode", aInt] -> putStrLn $ map (shift $ negate $ read $ aInt) message
    _ -> do 
      progName <- getProgName
      putStrLn ("Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [-encode|-decode] [0-9]")
      exitFailure
```

Comment: A few style notes: instead of integer literals with comments like `97 -- 97 is 'a' in ASCII`, it would be more readable to use `Data.Char.ord :: Char -> Int`, i.e., `ord 'a'`; it’s more common to use *guards* than `if … then … else …` at the top level of a function, like `shiftLeft shift char | isAsciiLower char = … | isAsciiUpper char = … | otherwise = …`; and finally, the `do` is unnecessary in `shiftLeft`/`shiftRight`, since `do x` = `x`; it’s not wrong, but generally the standard idiom is to use `do` only with monadic code.

Comment: Ah, TIL about [`ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) - looks to be the same as `fromEnum` but for Chars only. 

As for guards - this is brilliant, thank you! I was wondering, however: how do you handle nested if else statements other than with boolean operators like `&&` and `||`? Am I missing a cleaner way to do this, a way to avoid repeating `isAsciiUpper char` for example? 

I do not yet know what monadic code is, or what you mean about `do` - but I removed them from the functions. Thank you so much for all this feedback!

Comment: Also, just discovered `chr` as a result of your recommending I use `ord` (I wonder what `ord` stands for ...), so I went ahead and switched to using `chr` as well.

I also realized I could probably combine `shiftRight` and `shiftLeft` into the same function, and just pass a negative shift number into the combined function for `shiftLeft` and use a positive shift value for `shiftRight`. I will leave it for now, but it bugs me knowing it could be less redundant.

Comment: I lied, I couldn't leave it alone. I combined the two functions into `shift`. Unfortunately, it required I be a little more clever than I would like. I also read up on `case` and better understood it, so the changes reflect that as well.